# Substitution of 1/x in place of x in a function

Tags: functions

I came across this question while solving problems on functions.
"A function f(x) is defined for all real values of x as:
$5f(x) + 2f(\frac{1}{x}) = 4x + 2$. What is the value of f(2)?"

In the solution provided in the text:
The x in the above equation was substituted with 1/x.

$5f(\frac{1}{x}) + 2f(x) = \frac{4}{x} + 2. $

The two equations were then solved for f(x) and then the value of f(2) was found.

1. I don't understand why we can just substitute x with 1/x ( If f(x) is defined for all reals, then does it not mean f(1/x) doesn't exist for x = 0? If that is the case, why would they use f(1/x) in the question?)
2. I don't understand why we can treat the two equations as a system of linear equations. ( I realise I can look at f(x) as a variable a and f(1/x) as another variable b and solve the two equations, what I want to know is why functions can be treated this way)

Comment: 1) The problem makes an inaccurate statement in the first place, because clearly $5f(x)+2f(1/x)=4x+2$ can only hold for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Likewise, the substitution is only meant to hold for $x\ne 0$. 2) Equations are predicates about numbers and parameters, some of which we call variables because the are very super special (except that they aren't); solving an equation ultimately means (at least it should mean) transforming the predicate into a different one that is logically equivalent, but aestetically more pleasant. So everything can be treated as such.

Answer (score 2):

This problem isn't really treating functions in some special way.

That said, it is poorly written. The given expression should not be stated as the definition of a function. And you are correct that $0$ must be excluded from the domain. A better statement might be:

> Suppose there is a function $f$ such that for all $x \ne 0$ you know
> $$ 5f(x) + 2f(\frac{1}{x}) = 4x + 2 . $$ Find $f(2)$.

Then it is perfectly reasonable to assert that
$$
5f(2) + 2f(\frac{1}{2}) = 4\times 2 + 2
$$
and
$$
5f(\frac{1}{2}) + 2f(2) = 4\times \frac{1}{2}+ 2 .
$$
Now you have two equations in the two unknown numbers $f(2)$ and $f(1/2)$ to solve in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

1. The domain certainly does not include $0$ in the first place since otherwise $5f(x) + 2 f(\color{red}{1/x)} = 4x+2$ won't be defined. That justifies why the substitution $x \to \frac{1}{x}$ works.
2. You don't exactly treat them as linear equations. You just subtract and add them in a way similar to what you do with linear equations when you're trying to calculate the solutions (or zeroes).